# Using httpclient inside a loop

Tags: java, httpclient, connection

I have a class that I use for testing links. I pass the links to the class using a for loop. Inside my class I use httpclient to open the connection to the link. This can happen several thousand times. After a while I start to get timeouts, I presume this is to do with creating so many httpclients.

My question is, whats the best way to go about managing this(I'm a beginner fyi). Should I be closing connections, only using one httpclient etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the end of each loop you should do that `Webpage.close();`.

Another idea is to create the object outside the loops, and instantiate them inside. Something like:

```
WebPage obj = null;

while(true) {
    obj = new Object(); //I don't recall the correct arguments here

    //Processing

    obj.close;
}
```

Comment: Ooh, and these are best practices. You should always stick to them.

Comment: So what you are saying is I should create my httpclient outside of my loop. Run all the code I need to and once finished I would close my httpclinet?

Comment: Yup. You instantiate (Whuch basically means you create the object), and when you're done with the processing, you close it.